# Please verify that the Azure search resource in your QnAMaker service is up and running

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

I was using the newly launched virtual assistant template of the bot framework and deployed it, works fine however it did provision the Azure search service with standard tier which was needed for my scenario.

Since, there is no option to upgrade the pricing tier of azure search service - I had to delete the existing search service and provision a new one with basic tier and also associated it with QnA host service as mentioned in the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/upgrade-qnamaker-service#upgrade-azure-search-service

Essentially, I just configured the QnA maker host web app to know the newly created azure search service by updating settings as shown below and restarted the host app service.

[image]

After setting this, I expected that everything would work ok however when I browse the QnA maker service now, I see that my previously created knowledge bases are there however when I try to edit or publish them - I end up getting an error message which says - Runtime error. Unable to connect to azure search service. Please verify that the Azure search resource in your QnAMaker service is up and running.

[image]

Can you please help or suggest If we have missed anything?

Comment: I tried recreating your steps and it worked for me, doesn't throw up any error. Did you restore your knowledge base data to the upgraded Azure search SKU(step 2 in the documentation)? You will have to download the code linked there and change your source & target names and API keys and run it on Visual Studio, after which if you try to edit or publish the KB, you won't get the error. Let me know if you encounter any issues.

Comment: All right, ended up creating a new QnA and search service together. Seems I might have missed the step to back up and restore existing indexes in previous search service.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the exact question, but may help those looking to change the Search SKU.

For the Virtual Assistant template before you deploy your bot, edit the template.json file in the Deployment\Resources directory.  Edit the 'qnaMakerSearchSku' to be be basic or free depending on your needs.

```
"qnaMakerSearchSku": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "basic"
},
```